# How to stop Tkinter TextBox from terminating string on null character

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, null

I am new to tkinter and python, I need an editable textbox that supports null characters but

```
self.text.insert(tk.END, 'hello\0test')
```

displays only `hello`

I tried running  `print(self.text.get('1.0', tk.END))` which gives only `hello`

I am replacing the null character before assiging to TextBox for now `'hello\0test'.replace('\0', '\\x00')`. but after editing, converting the value `'\\x00'` back to `null` character becomes a problem if the input string already had `'\\x00'` that also will get converted to `null`.

Comment: I doubt that there is anything you can do. Since you won't be able to see the null characters, why are you wanting to insert them?

Comment: I wanted a custom UI for mitmproxy to edit HTTP requests and responses. Some of them have null character in them and breaks in the TextBox.